# How to start an Activity from Service Android 11

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-11

how can i open an Activity in the Background from my Service?

The App is running in background and an Intent Brodcast that triggers the start of an Activity within my app.

I tried it on an Android 8.1 Device and it works fine but on the Andrid 11 Device it wont work.

```
 public void StartRead(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             if(intent.getAction().equals(VariableStorage.getInstance().BRODCAST_READ)){
                 //Start RFID Activity
                    StartRead();
            }else if(intent.getAction().equals(VariableStorage.getInstance().BRODCAST_DECODEVDA)){
                //Decode VDA55
             }
        }
    };
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"/>
```

My Service is a normal ForegroundService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i open an Activity in the Background from my Service?

You can't.

The reason and your options is explained in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts):

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps start activities when the app runs in the background.

According to the android documentation you can't do this.

[Read more](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)